# Java: overloaded method resolution

Tags: java, compilation, overloading, method-resolution-order

So I have the following overloaded methods:

```
private static void foo(short... a)
{
    System.out.println("Calling var-len");
}

private static void foo(int a, int b)
{
    System.out.println("Calling int-int");
}

private static void foo(int a, double b) //(3)
{
    System.out.println("Calling int-double");
}

private static void main (String[] args)
{
    foo((short)2, (short)5); //This one outputs "Calling int-int"
}
```

I know that variable arity method has the lowest priority during method resolution phases, so in this case if I call `foo((short)2, (short)4);` I would get "Calling int-int".

HOWEVER, if I change method (3) to `foo(short a, double b)`, the variable arity method is picked! (Java 7).
Could anyone explain this?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Please post a full runnable test-case along with two sets of overloads (one showing behavior A, other other behavior B).

Comment: I ran the code myself, but I get an ambiguity error rather than going for the third method. Could you please post some tests?

Comment: Java 6_24 throws an ambiguous reference error during compile time, which IMHO is the correct thing to do according to the spec.

Comment: Well, I ran it, too and it doesn't throw the error. I compiled and ran just fine with java 7. Some people told me they had the error when running the program in java 6.

Comment: With Java 1.6 (OS X 10.6.8) I also get the varargs version. I guess I'm also curious as to why changing a method that should not be picked in either case would have an effect on which of the plausible two get picked. Seems like a non sequitur.

Comment: @Radiodef With the third method being (short, double), it is not possible to tell whether  (short, double) or (int, int), the two fixed-arity methods, is more *specific*. And because of that, it should be an "ambiguous" case. I am surprised Java is picking the varargs. The compiler should never look at variable-arity method(s) if thare are applicable fixed arity methods. (according to the spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1)

Comment: So the JVM just gave up and picked the variable arity one?

Comment: @OneTwoThree But then couldn't it plausibly move on to phase 3 if neither is more specific than the other? I've been reading the specs and so far I don't see a clause for that.

Comment: Ooooookay read the note under phase 1: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2 It says that variable arity methods are treated as fixed arity methods during phase 1.

Answer (score 2):

According to the specification:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2

*"However, the declaration of a variable arity method (§8.4.1) can change the method chosen for a given method method invocation expression, because a variable arity method is treated as a fixed arity method in the first phase."*

Comment: How does that explain why Java picks the variable-arity method? Could you be more specific?

Comment: In the case of foo #2 having types `int, int` and foo #3 having types `short, double` passing both shorts to the methods I guess results in neither of the methods being more specific than the other. In that case as the doc says, I guess the variable arity one is evaluated as being `short, short`.

Comment: @OneTwoThree I don't really find this to be a satisfying answer either. If true, basically it would simply mean that the variable arity methods are evaluated _as fixed arity but last in the first phase_. But I don't see anything else in the specs that would indicate this as plausible behavior.

Comment: Right, that's what I was getting at. No where in the spec was this case mentioned. I wonder if this is just a bug that hasn't been filed on the Java compiler!

Comment: It also seems strange we are getting different results depending on the Java version. I think you and I are both on Java 6 but I'm on update 65. I don't think that should make a difference.

Comment: I'm on RHE6, Java 1.6, update 24. And I am getting the expected ambiguous compile-time error. I guess they "added" the bug somewhere between the updates!

Comment: @abcXYZ is on Java 7. Maybe I will try this on my XP desktop for kicks and see what happens. I wonder if they changed something in one of the updates since 24.

Comment: Oh interesting, trying to actually build and compile to a JAR produces the warning for me. It is runnable inside the IDE but refuses to compile. That's curious. As it should be I guess but beats me why the IDE runs it anyway. Not something I know about. OP, did you try to actually compile it to a JAR?

Answer (score -3):

Your question is a typical example for numerical promotion in java. It tries to resolve for the exact signature match (short, short), but in your case you don't have that method. Java checks for subsequent compatible data type (say int), it promotes both short to int data types and tries to find a match, it finds it.

If none of the numeric promotion works, it will resolve to variable argument method in your code.

Please read on numeric promotions on below link..
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: If it promotes the args, shouldn't the method that takes `int, int` be picked?

Comment: I believe the OP knows the shorts are being promoted. The question is why changing the third method from `int, double` to `short, double` results in the varargs method being chosen over the int method. The question is why changing a method that is assumed to be never called changes which of the two methods does get called. It seems non sequitur.